Poor Samsung 980 Pro 2TB NVME Performance Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. Ryzen 5950X Aorus Ultra x570
Poor disk performance shown by fio when compared to an intel 13900k on ubuntu20 (also real world database queries significantly slower)
My FIO here is showing 900Mib/s and 230kIOPS. I have this exact same drive in another machine on ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and its more than double these numbers and the db performance is way better. I have posted output from smartctl, fdisk, lwhw and other tools below. Let me know what other tool output you may need. I owe you one if you can figure this out. Thanks!
matt@ryzen:~$ sudo fio --name=randread --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=32 --rw=randread --bs=4k --direct=1 --size=20G --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting --filename=/dev/nvme0n1
randread: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
fio-3.36
Starting 1 process
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [r(1)][100.0%][r=900MiB/s][r=230k IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
randread: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=7675: Thu Aug  8 18:59:38 2024
  read: IOPS=231k, BW=904MiB/s (948MB/s)(20.0GiB/22661msec)
    slat (nsec): min=1980, max=205244, avg=3177.38, stdev=1851.76
    clat (usec): min=14, max=8503, avg=134.81, stdev=33.55
     lat (usec): min=16, max=8520, avg=137.99, stdev=33.58
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   67],  5.00th=[  106], 10.00th=[  115], 20.00th=[  121],
     | 30.00th=[  125], 40.00th=[  128], 50.00th=[  133], 60.00th=[  137],
     | 70.00th=[  141], 80.00th=[  147], 90.00th=[  165], 95.00th=[  184],
     | 99.00th=[  221], 99.50th=[  239], 99.90th=[  285], 99.95th=[  310],
     | 99.99th=[  388]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=911640, max=932176, per=100.00%, avg=925778.13, stdev=4066.29, samples=45
   iops        : min=227910, max=233044, avg=231444.67, stdev=1016.52, samples=45
  lat (usec)   : 20=0.01%, 50=0.04%, 100=4.01%, 250=95.62%, 500=0.32%
  lat (usec)   : 750=0.01%, 1000=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.01%, 4=0.01%, 10=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=18.63%, sys=81.29%, ctx=407, majf=0, minf=42
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=100.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.1%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=5242880,0,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=904MiB/s (948MB/s), 904MiB/s-904MiB/s (948MB/s-948MB/s), io=20.0GiB (21.5GB), run=22661-22661msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  nvme0n1: ios=5239998/55, sectors=41919984/584, merge=0/5, ticks=411503/14, in_queue=411521, util=99.59%

matt@ryzen:~$ uname -a
Linux ryzen 6.8.0-40-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul  5 10:34:03 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

matt@ryzen:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
VERSION_CODENAME=noble
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=noble
LOGO=ubuntu-logo

sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.8.0-39-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 980 PRO with Heatsink 2TB
Serial Number:                      S6WRNS0T228839V
Firmware Version:                   5B2QGXA7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      6
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            631,692,365,824 [631 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 b22140e5af
Local Time is:                      Thu Aug  8 18:55:53 2024 PDT
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x0057):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x0f):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg Ext_Get_Lg Telmtry_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         128 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     82 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     8.49W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.48W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0     200
 2 +     3.18W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0    1000
 3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2000    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4      500    9500

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        54 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    4%
Data Units Read:                    579,552,917 [296 TB]
Data Units Written:                 180,872,419 [92.6 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 36,068,216,253
Host Write Commands:                1,426,035,934
Controller Busy Time:               13,042
Power Cycles:                       153
Power On Hours:                     1,673
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   43
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    21
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               54 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               58 Celsius
Thermal Temp. 1 Transition Count:   7
Thermal Temp. 2 Transition Count:   3
Thermal Temp. 1 Total Time:         2595
Thermal Temp. 2 Total Time:         151

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
No Errors Logged

Self-test Log (NVMe Log 0x06)
Self-test status: No self-test in progress
No Self-tests Logged

matt@ryzen:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
[sudo] password for matt: 
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 980 PRO with Heatsink 2TB   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8979C299-5C10-4E42-BA0D-9C2C74B10373

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    2203647    2201600    1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 2203648 3907026943 3904823296  1.8T Linux filesystem

matt@ryzen:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,MODEL,SIZE,VENDOR
[sudo] password for matt: 
NAME        MODEL                                   SIZE VENDOR
loop0                                                 4K 
loop1                                              74.2M 
loop2                                              74.2M 
loop3                                              67.8M 
loop4                                             269.6M 
loop5                                             269.8M 
loop6                                              10.7M 
loop7                                             505.1M 
loop8                                               1.5M 
loop9                                              91.7M 
loop10                                             99.6M 
loop11                                             10.3M 
loop12                                             10.5M 
loop13                                             38.7M 
loop14                                             38.8M 
loop15                                              476K 
nvme2n1     Sabrent Rocket 4.0 1TB                931.5G 
├─nvme2n1p1                                          16M 
└─nvme2n1p2                                       931.5G 
nvme0n1     Samsung SSD 980 PRO with Heatsink 2TB   1.8T 
├─nvme0n1p1                                           1G 
└─nvme0n1p2                                         1.8T 
nvme1n1     Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB          931.5G 
└─nvme1n1p1                                       931.5G 

matt@ryzen:~$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path                          Device          Class          Description
============================================================================
                                                  system         TEST (Default string)
/0                                                bus            TEST2
/0/0                                              memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/b                                              memory         64GiB System Memory
/0/b/0                                            memory         16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/b/1                                            memory         16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/b/2                                            memory         16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/b/3                                            memory         16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/e                                              memory         1MiB L1 cache
/0/f                                              memory         8MiB L2 cache
/0/10                                             memory         64MiB L3 cache
/0/11                                             processor      AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor
/0/100                                            bridge         Starship/Matisse Root Complex
/0/100/0.2                                        generic        Starship/Matisse IOMMU
/0/100/1.1                                        bridge         Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.1/0                      /dev/nvme0      storage        Samsung SSD 980 PRO with Heatsink 2TB
/0/100/1.1/0/0                    hwmon3          disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1.1/0/2                    /dev/ng0n1      disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1.1/0/1                    /dev/nvme0n1    disk           2TB NVMe disk
/0/100/1.1/0/1/1                  /dev/nvme0n1p1  volume         1074MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1.1/0/1/2                  /dev/nvme0n1p2  volume         1861GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1.2                                        bridge         Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0                                      bridge         Matisse Switch Upstream
/0/100/1.2/0/0                                    bridge         Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/0/0                  /dev/nvme1      storage        Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB
/0/100/1.2/0/0/0/0                hwmon2          disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1.2/0/0/0/2                /dev/ng1n1      disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1.2/0/0/0/1                /dev/nvme1n1    disk           1TB NVMe disk
/0/100/1.2/0/0/0/1/1              /dev/nvme1n1p1  volume         931GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1.2/0/1                                    bridge         Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/1/0                  /dev/nvme2      storage        Sabrent Rocket 4.0 1TB
/0/100/1.2/0/1/0/0                hwmon1          disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1.2/0/1/0/2                /dev/ng2n1      disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1.2/0/1/0/1                /dev/nvme2n1    disk           1TB NVMe disk
/0/100/1.2/0/1/0/1/1              /dev/nvme2n1p1  volume         931GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1.2/0/1/0/1/2              /dev/nvme2n1p2  volume         931GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1.2/0/3                                    bridge         Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/3/0                  wlp6s0          network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/1.2/0/4                                    bridge         Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/4/0                  enp7s0          network        I211 Gigabit Network Connection
/0/100/1.2/0/8                                    bridge         Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0                                  generic        Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.1                                bus            Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.1/0              usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.1/0/1                            input          ITE Device(8595)
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.1/0/6                            bus            USB2.0 Hub
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.1/1              usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3                                bus            Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/0              usb3            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/0/4            scsi10          storage        USB 2.0 FD
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/0/4/0.0.0      /dev/sda        disk           31GB USB 2.0 FD
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/0/4/0.0.0/0    /dev/sda        disk           31GB 
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/0/4/0.0.0/0/2  /dev/sda2       volume         15EiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/0/5                            communication  AX200 Bluetooth
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/0/6                            bus            USB2.0 Hub
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/0/6/4                          input          Back-UPS ES 650G1 FW:906.W1 .D USB FW:W1
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/1              usb4            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/1/3            scsi11          storage        Sabrent
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/1/3/0.0.0      /dev/sdb        disk           1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/1/3/0.0.0/2    /dev/sdb2       volume         15EiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3/1/3/0.0.0/3    /dev/sdb3       volume         927GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1.2/0/9                                    bridge         Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/9/0                                  storage        FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1.2/0/a                                    bridge         Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/a/0                                  storage        FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/3.1                                        bridge         Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
/0/100/3.1/0                                      display        GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090]
/0/100/3.1/0.1                    card0           multimedia     GA102 High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/3.1/0.1/0                  input10         input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/0/100/3.1/0.1/1                  input11         input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/0/100/3.1/0.1/2                  input8          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/3.1/0.1/3                  input9          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/7.1                                        bridge         Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
/0/100/7.1/0                                      generic        Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
/0/100/8.1                                        bridge         Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
/0/100/8.1/0                                      generic        Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
/0/100/8.1/0.1                                    generic        Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
/0/100/8.1/0.3                                    bus            Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0                  usb5            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/1                                bus            USB2.0 Hub
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/1/1                              bus            Virtual HUB
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/1/1/1            input19         input          USB Keyboard
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/1/1/6            input26         input          Generic Virtual HID Consumer Control
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/1/2                              input          USB Receiver
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/1/2/0            input25         input          Logitech Performance MX
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1                  usb6            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.4                    card1           multimedia     Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.4/0                  input12         input          HD-Audio Generic Front Mic
/0/100/8.1/0.4/1                  input13         input          HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic
/0/100/8.1/0.4/2                  input14         input          HD-Audio Generic Line
/0/100/8.1/0.4/3                  input15         input          HD-Audio Generic Line Out Front
/0/100/8.1/0.4/4                  input16         input          HD-Audio Generic Line Out Surround
/0/100/8.1/0.4/5                  input17         input          HD-Audio Generic Line Out CLFE
/0/100/8.1/0.4/6                  input18         input          HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone
/0/100/14                                         bus            FCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.3                                       bridge         FCH LPC Bridge
/0/100/14.3/0                                     system         PnP device PNP0c01
/0/100/14.3/1                                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/14.3/2                                     system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/100/14.3/3                                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/14.3/4                                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/101                                            bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/102                                            bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/103                                            bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/104                                            bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/105                                            bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/106                                            bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/107                                            bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/108                                            bridge         Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
/0/109                                            bridge         Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
/0/10a                                            bridge         Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
/0/10b                                            bridge         Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
/0/10c                                            bridge         Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
/0/10d                                            bridge         Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
/0/10e                                            bridge         Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
/0/10f                                            bridge         Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
/1                                /dev/fb0        display        simpledrmdrmfb
/2                                input0          input          Power Button
/3                                input1          input          Power Button

matt@ryzen:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
isofs                  61440  1
uas                    28672  2
usb_storage            90112  1 uas
tls                   151552  0
rfcomm                 98304  4
snd_seq_dummy          12288  0
snd_hrtimer            12288  1
ccm                    20480  6
nvidia_uvm           1806336  0
qrtr                   53248  4
cmac                   12288  3
algif_hash             12288  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   32768  2
binfmt_misc            24576  1
nls_iso8859_1          12288  1
hid_logitech_hidpp     65536  0
joydev                 32768  0
input_leds             12288  0
nvidia_drm             94208  9
iwlmvm                864256  0
nvidia_modeset       1314816  12 nvidia_drm
mac80211             1728512  1 iwlmvm
snd_hda_codec_realtek   200704  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   122880  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     94208  1
libarc4                12288  1 mac80211
snd_hda_intel          61440  2
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     16384  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
btusb                  77824  0
snd_hda_codec         217088  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
btrtl                  36864  1 btusb
iwlwifi               610304  1 iwlmvm
btintel                57344  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
snd_hda_core          151552  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
btmtk                  16384  1 btusb
nvidia              56827904  510 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
bluetooth            1032192  34 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
intel_rapl_common      40960  1 intel_rapl_msr
ccp                   143360  0
hid_logitech_dj        36864  0
ecc                    45056  1 ecdh_generic
cfg80211             1339392  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
snd_pcm               200704  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           24576  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            57344  1 snd_seq_midi
edac_mce_amd           28672  0
crct10dif_pclmul       12288  1
polyval_clmulni        12288  0
snd_seq               118784  9 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy
polyval_generic        12288  1 polyval_clmulni
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
sha256_ssse3           32768  0
sha1_ssse3             32768  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
aesni_intel           356352  8
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 28672  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
snd                   147456  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
gigabyte_wmi           12288  0
rapl                   20480  0
wmi_bmof               12288  0
mxm_wmi                12288  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
video                  73728  1 nvidia_modeset
k10temp                16384  0
i2c_piix4              32768  0
mac_hid                12288  0
msr                    12288  0
parport_pc             53248  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     28672  0
parport                77824  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
efi_pstore             12288  0
nfnetlink              20480  1
dmi_sysfs              24576  0
ip_tables              36864  0
x_tables               69632  1 ip_tables
autofs4                57344  2
hid_generic            12288  0
usbhid                 77824  3 hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
hid                   184320  4 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
nvme                   61440  2
crc32_pclmul           12288  0
igb                   319488  0
ahci                   49152  0
libahci                57344  1 ahci
nvme_core             212992  3 nvme
xhci_pci               24576  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 igb
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
dca                    16384  1 igb
nvme_auth              28672  1 nvme_core
wmi                    32768  4 video,gigabyte_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi


Your question says Ubuntu 24 in the title and Ubuntu 20 in the question. Both of these are version numbers for Ubuntu Core, the only version of Ubuntu to use only a single digit version. If you are not running Ubuntu Core please edit the question and add the actual version info. As well is it 20 or 24 the title and question do not match.

Thanks, I edited that information, although I did post that information via a cat /etc/os-release in my question body.

Samsung releases firmware updates. Here is an old link I had on file for the 960 pro: https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/

This is a samsung 980 pro 2tb with latest firmware . The sectors are aligned... I show both of these in the body of my original post. See the smartctl and fdisk output in my original post

It appears to have something to do with the asus aorus x570 ultra nvme controller or ubuntu 24.04. When I moved the drive to the intel machine running ubuntu 20.04.6 lts on a gigabyte b760m ds3h board the numbers doubled. sudo fio --name=randread --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=32 --rw=randread --bs=4k --direct=1 --size=20G --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting --filename=/dev/nvme1n1
randread: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
fio-3.16
Starting 1 process
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [r(1)][100.0%][r=1860MiB/s][r=476k IOPS][eta 00m:
